# Not able to calculate time intervals larger than 20 seconds in C

Tags: c, time

I am currently working on a project in which I am required to calculate the maximum input for the following program for a given execution time.

The program goes as this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() 
{
    long long int n = 0;
    int a0 = 0, a1 = 1, s = 0, i = 0, T = 0, j = 0;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    clock_t start, end;
    double timtaken;
    start = clock();
    for(j = 1 ; j <= n ; j++)
    {
      s = (a1 + a0) % 2014;
      a0 = a1 % 2014;
      a1 = s;
    }
    a1 = 1;
    a0 = 0;
    end = clock();
    timtaken = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time taken is %.9f\n", timtaken);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem didn't give any compilation errors and worked fine till the input 2x10<sup>9</sup>.
Any input greater than this the compiler is taking too much time but doesn't give the output.
The output for 2x10<sup>9</sup> was around 18 seconds in my pc.
I don't understand why this is happening.
I have installed C compiler through MinGW.

Comment: Compilers don't give output. Why are you trying this in [tag:c]?

Comment: I just need the execution time.I am using C as the project specifies to use that.@iharob

Comment: there would be `long long`, but I do not get what kind of calculations you are using here ... Do you need higher precision that seconds ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve] example.

Comment: What does "Any input 2*10^9 or greater the compiler didn't give the output." mean? Does it crash?

Comment: no.I am seeking the largest n for which the execution is 1min,2min,10min,etc through this program.@Marged

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `scanf("%lld",&n);`  1) the user will be staring at a blinking cursor, with no idea of what to do next.  Suggest prefixing each call to `scanf()` with a prinf() prompt indicating what the user is expected to input.  2) always check the returned value from calls to `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.  3) in the current scenario, the 'n' needs to be unsigned.

Comment: regarding this line: `for(j=1;j<=n;j++)`   In the current scenario, this is acceptable as 'j' is not referenced within the loop, however, for most scenarios, the correct statement would be: `for( j=0; j<n; j++ )`

Comment: What was the next input greater than 2x10^9 you tried? How long do you expect it to take? We should probably solve this with maths - I suspect it is just taking orders of magnitude longer when you give it bigger numbers.

Comment: How long is "too much time"? Did you wait 15 minutes before cancelling the program?

Comment: The output for 10^9 was around 9 secondsThe output for 2x10^9 was around 18 seconds.The next input was 5*10^9Considering the program is of linear order the time should be lesser than a minute.I waited for around 20 minutes still without an answer.@doctorlove @pmg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing an `int` and a `long long int`. They have different ranges.

If the `long long int` value falls outside the range of `int` all bets are off!

```
for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
```

The comparison `j <= n` is error prone.
`j` is first converted to `long long int`, then compared.
Afterwards, when `j` is back to being an `int` is is increased and overflows invoking Undefined Behaviour (probably it goes back to the beginning of its range: `-2,147,483,648`).

Make `j` also a `long long int` object.

*<sub>I guess the range of `int` on your computer does not go beyond `2,147,483,647` (or `2.1x10^9`).</sub>*

Comment: Thanks it worked @pmg

Answer (score 0):

Suggest writing the code like this as it is very human friendly and incorporates error checking and does not limit the loop counter:

Note: the main problem was the loop counter `j` was limited to 2gig, but `n` was not.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <math.h>
#include  <time.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned long long int n;

    int a0=0;
    int a1=1;
    int s=0;
    //int i=0;
    //int T=0;
    //int j=0;
    unsigned long long int j;

    // note: format string:  unsigned and leading space to consume white space
    if( 1 != scanf(" %llu",&n) ) 
    { // then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;
    double timtaken;

    // Note: 'n' already initialized by call to scanf()
    for( ; n>0; n-- )
    {
        start=clock();

        for( j=0; j<n; j++ )
        {
            s=(a1+a0)%2014;
            a0=a1%2014;
            a1=s;
        }

        a1=1;
        a0=0;

        end=clock();
        timtaken=((double)(end-start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf( "time taken is %.9f\n", timtaken );

        if( 1 != scanf(" %llu",&n) )
        { // then scanf failed
            perror( "scanf failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: "leading space to consume white space" in `scanf()` for `"%llu"` (and most other conversion specifiers) is redundant. The specifier already includes ignoring leading white space.

Comment: true about the format specifier 'llu' consuming leading white space.   I included that info because most beginning programmers in C, when using the '%s' format specifier do not handle any leading white space (usually performed via call(s) to `getchar()`.  So this is just a 'heads up' teaching aid.

Comment: The answer to the question is given in the "note", the rest is just comment.  Comments posted as answers should be avoided.

Comment: @Clifford, the posted code in the answer incorporates the comments on the original question..  And If all I posted was the note, then several persons would have either downvoted it or written comments similar to yours.  As it is, for most of those new C programmers, this is a learning experience, so I try to provide code as an example of a style that is very human readable and understandable.  This helps them to avoid producing unreadable code.  thereby making them better programmers.\